# Add zeroDateTimeBehavior variable to the Datasource without URL in jetty.xml

Tags: database, timestamp, jetty, jndi, hikaricp

I'm trying to connect to multiple data sources by a grails application. What I tried worked in a development environment correctly. Initially there was a timestamp error which got resolved with '`zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull`' adding to a url. But now in production environment, I don't understand how to add this variable.

My development environment code is,

```
dataSource_test {
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
            dbCreate = "validate" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
            username = "root"
            password = "root"
        }
```

And my production environment code is

```
dataSource_test{
            dbCreate = "validate"
            jndiName = "java:comp/env/jdbc/test"
        }
```

I've also added this datasource to jetty.xml as following,

```
 <New id="DS" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg><Ref refid="Server"/></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/test</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <New class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
        <Arg>
          <New class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
        <Set name="minimumIdle"><Property name="db.min.conn" /></Set>
            <Set name="maximumPoolSize"><Property name="db.max.conn" /></Set>
            <Set name="dataSourceClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource</Set>
            <Set name="username"><Property name="db.user" /></Set>
            <Set name="password"><Property name="db.pass" /></Set>
            <Call name="addDataSourceProperty">
              <Arg>url</Arg>
              <Arg>jdbc:mysql://<Property name="db.host" />/test</Arg>
            </Call>
            <Set name="leakDetectionThreshold">30000</Set>
          </New>
        </Arg>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </New>
```

I don't understand where should I put "`zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull`" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just a property on the mysql side of the DataSource.

Just set it (like you do the url)

This should work (like any other property for the mysql datasource)

```xml
<Call name="addDataSourceProperty">
  <Arg>zeroDateTimeBehavior</Arg>
  <Arg>convertToNull</Arg>
</Call>
```